# Замена первых символов после

Tags: delphi

**Есть текстовом файл со строками:**

```
/12/Makros2334%54a.17/1a1b/1c
-1-Makros%534a.17-2a1-v
>4>5>Makros%534a.17>4g>1
```

Как, именно через функцию **StringReplace**, заменить первые символы  (**-** и **>**) что находятся после символа **процент (%)** **на один символ (/)**.

**На выходе должно получится:**

```
/12/Makros2334%54a.17/1a1b/1c
-1-Makros%534a.17/2a1-v
 >4>5>Makros%534a.17/4g>1
```

Стандартный код вот:
Я так понимаю что **скобки [] в StringReplace** означают - замена идет до первого вхождения. Но нужно что бы замена **происходила после символа** (%)  и дальше уже замена до первого вхождения.

```
s := StringReplace(s,'-','/',[]);
s := StringReplace(s,'>','/',[]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

примерно так (кажется)

```
var
  f1,f2,q1,q2: Integer;
  s: String;
  t: TStringList;
begin
  s:= '->';
  t:= TStringList.Create;
  t.LoadFromFile('123.txt');
  for f1:=0 to t.Count-1 do
  begin
    q1:= Pos('%', t.Strings[f1]);
    if q1>0 then begin
      for f2:=1 to Length(s) do begin
        q2:= PosEx(s[f2], t.Strings[f1], q1+1);
        if q2>0 then
          t.Strings[f1]:= Copy(t.Strings[f1], 1, q2-1)+'/'+Copy(t.Strings[f1], q2+1, Length(t.Strings[f1])-q2)
      end;
    end;
    memo.Lines.Add(t.Strings[f1]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Работает отлично. +